# Tradução dentro do perfil

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

Locais

- Perfil - Aba participação - Dentro da barra para o próximo privilégio
- Perfil - Aba participação - Aba reputação - Lado esquerdo do gráfico

Olhando com mais atenção notei o seguinte:

- Ao passar o mouse pelo gráfico os dias da semana aparecem em
  inglês mas os meses em português.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você está se referindo aos números?

Comment: @Math Não, o primeiro está como access review queues e o segundo reputation per day.

Comment: Poderia adicionar um print? O _acess review queue_ se refere ao privilégio, e entendi onde está, mas o _reputation per day_ não aparece para mim.

Comment: feito, editado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As traduções foram feitas e já estão no ar.

Comment: `status-pronto` :)